# how to fix axes position by using set_position method in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, position, axes

I think this is quite easy but I searched the internet and matplotlib users mailing list and not able to find an answer. ax2 is an inset axes within the "ax" axes in figure "fig", which I make by following here:
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html

but now my problem is that I cannot fix the ax2 the exact position I want,  it seems that draw() command change this:

```
In [352]:
ax2.set_position([0.125,0.63,0.25,0.25])

In [353]:
ax2.get_position()

Out[353]:
Bbox(array([[ 0.125,  0.63 ],
       [ 0.375,  0.88 ]]))

In [354]:
draw()

In [355]:
ax2.get_position()

Out[355]:
Bbox(array([[ 0.15625,  0.63   ],
       [ 0.34375,  0.88   ]]))
```

notice that, after "draw()" command, the x0 of ax2 changed. could anyone give any hints?

thanks!

Comment: What data is being plotted? I'm particularly interested in the x axis scaling.

Comment: what do you mean by a axis scaling?

Comment: I did a test on my side, and got different results:


    `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

    `fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.75))`


    `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)`

    `ax2.set_position([0.125,0.63,0.25,0.25])`

    `ax2.get_position()`

    `Bbox(array([[ 0.125,  0.63 ],[ 0.375,  0.88 ]]))`

    `plt.draw()`
    `ax2.get_position()`

    `Bbox(array([[ 0.125,  0.63 ],[ 0.375,  0.88 ]]))`

Comment: As for x-axis scaling, I misunderstood the question originally. :) I was referring to the range in which the x-data falls. That shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: yes. I forgot to add following comments. Actually in my script there is one step to set equal aspect. I guess when I use draw, it applies this command and the default anchor for set_aspect ('equal') is 'center'  I guess. That's why the position changed.

Comment: wiswit: It might be a good idea to answer your own question. This helps when people have the same question as you, they can find the answer easily.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the position by specifying the parameters as a `Bbox` object:

```
>>> ax2.set_position(matplotlib.transforms.Bbox(array([[0.125,0.63],[0.25,0.25]])))
>>> ax2.get_position()
Bbox(array([[ 0.125,  0.63 ],
       [ 0.25 ,  0.25 ]]))
>>> draw()
>>> ax2.get_position()
Bbox(array([[ 0.125,  0.63 ],
       [ 0.25 ,  0.25 ]]))
```

With this you can see the settings are round-tripping like you would expect.

In addition, you could instead look at the results as a `tuple` like so:

```
>>> a.set_position([0.125,0.63,0.25,0.25])
>>> a.get_position().bounds
(0.125, 0.63, 0.25, 0.25)
```

It just depends if you want to look at the location/position as a bounding box: `x0,y0` by `x1,y1`, or instead by a location and size: `x,y,width,height`.

Currently you are telling it to set a `x,y,width,height`, then it's telling you the `x0,y0,x1,y1`.