# Change position of a parasite axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an axes object and a parasite axes within that axes (variable `ax` of type `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.parasite_axes.AxesHostAxes`). I want to change the position of the parasite axes (for example it's width), but using `ax.set_position()` doesn't change the position.

I tried both this:

```
pos = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([pos.x0, pos.y0, pos.width - 0.1, pos.height])
```

and this:

```
ax.set_position(matplotlib.tranforms.Bbox(
   np.array([pos.x0, pos.y0], [pos.width - 0.1, pos.height])))
```

but the position remains unchanged.

Not that I am running matplotlib in interactive mode, so `draw()` is called after every change. A related question where `draw` resets position ignoring the one specified with `set_position()`: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971926/how-to-fix-axes-position-by-using-set-position-method-in-python-matplotlib)

In my case however the aspect is not 'equal' - it is 'auto'.